# Magento Programatically customer login not working in REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account

I am trying to customer login programatically for REST API with below script, but it always shows "Invalid login or password" but actually those are working from controller or login through website

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
     $status = $session->login($data['email'],$data['pwd']);
```

Is there any way to customer login check

Answer (score 0):

I use **loginById()** in my code for this purpose:

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
 $customer->loadByEmail($email);
 Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting  email and password through REST API , we cant provide directly login. i should verify the user name & password

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for that,

```
$status = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId('1')->authenticate($email, $password);
```